# Is $(\sum_{k=0}^n \sin(k!))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is a relatively easy exercice to show that $(\sum_{k=0}^n \sin(k))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is bounded by considering complex exponentials $e^{ik}$ (that form a geometric sum) and then taking the imaginary part. But what happens when we replace $k$ by $k!$ ?

I think that it is bounded by analogy. The terms somehow compensate one another... But I was unsucessfull at proving it.

One of my attempts : I tried to prove that $n!$ is an equidistributed sequence mod $2 \pi$ (I'm not sure that's true), but even with that I struggle to conclude.

Comment: Well, $\sum_{k=0}^n\sin(n!\pi e)$ is bounded, due to the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, but I doubt that'll help you here.

Comment: It should be noted that, for instance, the sequence $\sum_{k=0}^n\sin(k^2)$ are not bounded, even though squares are equidistributed modulo $2\pi$. Your problem is probably even harder than that, since I doubt we know much about distribution of $k!$ mod $2\pi$.

Comment: [Reference to my previous comment](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/the-van-der-corputs-trick-and-equidistribution-on-nilmanifolds/#comment-383528)

Comment: @Wojowu Why "even though" they are equidistributed?  If $X_n$ were i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $S^1$, I would expect $\sum_{k=0}^n \sin (X_k)$ to be almost surely unbounded since the standard deviation would be proportional to $\sqrt{n+1}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler "even though" because this has been OP's attempt (and that example implies this approach can't work).